# element.style in chrome element inspector?

Tags: css, google-chrome, styles, google-chrome-devtools

When I inspect elements in Chrome, under my styles I have `element.style {}`, What does this refer to? It contains styles I am not including in my code source.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Those are inline styles.
They come from the `style=""` attribute or from Javascript code that sets `element.style.someProperty`.