# Cannot find CSS style element in code, yet it exist in the DOM

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dom, owl-carousel

This code in the "element.style" exist in the DOM, but I cannot find it in the code I have. Another thing is that in the DOM it'll usually say where the code is (example: line 871), but it doesn't display that in this particular case. I have no idea why. Cannot anyone shed some insight to this?

If it helps at all I am using a Bootstrap theme and this particular portion involves the "owl carousel" [DOM image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyeWo.png)

Comment: your question title is about a style *element*, your image shows a style *attribute*, and your question seems to be referring to `element.style` which is a *property*. Can you please clarify what you are asking about?

Comment: It's probably from some js or inline style. Duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711300/element-style-in-chrome-element-inspector

Comment: @chiliNUT He is speaking about the element.style, the context point to it. Because he can't editting this with css. Or find this property with jquery function

Comment: @TBB yeah, duplicated.

Comment: @chillNUT I'm referring to the element.style. Where is it located in my code so that I can edit it? I edited in within the DOM and it works perfectly, so then I try to find it in my code and have no luck when searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, this style information is being added by JavaScript code.  Specifically, if there's an "owl.carousel.js" floating around in your codebase, look for JQuery `css` calls that will look something like this example (from my copy of "owl.carousel.js"):

```
$this.css({"width": base.itemWidth})
```

Comment: There is an "owl.carousel.min.js" and an "owl.carousel.css". Do you think it might be in one of these?

Comment: Yes, it would probably be in "owl.carousel.min.js", which is unlikely to make for easy reading.

Comment: Yeah, that code is a lot of horizontal bullshit. It doesn't show width or anything. Thinking I might just delete the carousel and put up my own divs or....something as an easier alternative.

Comment: I solved my problem by trying something completely different. I just labeled the one div different from the other and it allowed me to fix it in a completely different way. Apologies if this was a "noob" post, but what can I say other than...I'm a noob.

Comment: The post was okay, but note that you never said you had a problem you were trying to solve, just that you wanted an explanation of what you were seeing.  Glad you figured it out, though.